# datepicker view is hidden behind the div

Tags: html, angular, css-tables, bootstrap-table

These datepickers are listed in table rows. Datepickers in top rows are working fine (like in the first image). But datepickers in bottom rows are not showing properly (like in the second picture). **This issue only appears in mobile view.**

I've used bootstrap's `table-responsive` class for div witch contains this table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <datepicker datepicker-mobile="true" date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" ><input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2" ng-model="my_date"/>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table
</div>
```

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: @Hanif 720kb.datepicker...

Comment: I think this is happening for .table-responsive class in mobile view and your datepicker appearing inside this boundary that's why cutting off. However you can try set attribute 'datepicker-append-to="body".

Comment: @Hanif to datepicker..? like <date-picker datepicker-append-to="body" /> ..?

Comment: Exactly, see here: https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker "Doc" section, let me know if it work for you.

Comment: @Hanif no buddy, it doesn't help.. :(

Comment: You should try <datepicker not <date-picker

Comment: @Hanif .. Ah yah.. <datepicker datepicker-append-to="body"/> didn't work.... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170841/discussion-between-hanif-and-pumayk-26).

Answer (score 0):

datepicker-append-to should be body, so that it would be hidden inside the table.

```
> <datepicker datepicker-mobile="true" datepicker-append-to="body"
> date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" ><input type="text" class="form-control
> col-xs-2" ng-model="my_date"/>
```